# Parsing uploaded files without passing key

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I want to upload multiple files in a single request.

Is there a predefined parser which parses files(including content) without passing key of the file in wsgi or django. I want to get all the files from the request by passing index of the file.

For example in .net we have `Request.Files.Count` will give number of files uploaded.
And `Request.Files[0]` will give file at index zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.FILES` is a dictionary-like object that contains UploadedFile objects, which are lightweight wrappers around the uploaded files. Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploadedfile-objects for more details on what functionality is exposed by these wrappers.

To answer your question more succinctly, this means you don't need a custom parser to access multiple files. For more detailed information on accessing data in dictionaries, refer to http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries.